# I need to store extra user data in JWT access token

Tags: java, spring, security, jwt, token

I need to store the authenticated user's firstName and id in my access token, but when calling the attribute, the data returns empty.
Note that I first add the claim.

```
public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> tokenCustomizer() {
        return context -> {
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken principal = context.getPrincipal();
            CustomUserAuthorities user = (CustomUserAuthorities) principal.getDetails();
            List<String> authorities = user.getAuthorities().stream().map(x -> x.getAuthority()).toList();
            if (context.getTokenType().getValue().equals("access_token")) {
                // @formatter:off
                context.getClaims()
                        .claim("firstName", user.getFirstName())
                        .claim("authorities", authorities)
                        .claim("username", user.getUsername())
                        .claim("firstName", user.getFirstName())
                ;
                // @formatter:on
            }
        };
    }
```

I'm calling a separate CustomUserAuthorities class with custom attributes.

```
public class CustomUserAuthorities {

    private String username;
    private String firstName;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public CustomUserAuthorities(String firstName, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.username = username;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

In the CustomPasswordAuthenticationProvider class I called firstName and instantiated it by calling oAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken.getDetails.

```
public class CustomPasswordAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String ERROR_URI = "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.2";
    private final OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    private String firstName = "";
    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";
    private Set<String> authorizedScopes = new HashSet<>();

    public CustomPasswordAuthenticationProvider(OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService,
            OAuth2TokenGenerator<? extends OAuth2Token> tokenGenerator, 
            UserDetailsService userDetailsService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        
        Assert.notNull(authorizationService, "authorizationService cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(tokenGenerator, "TokenGenerator cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService, "UserDetailsService cannot be null");
        Assert.notNull(passwordEncoder, "PasswordEncoder cannot be null");
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
        this.tokenGenerator = tokenGenerator;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        
        CustomPasswordAuthenticationToken customPasswordAuthenticationToken = (CustomPasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken clientPrincipal = getAuthenticatedClientElseThrowInvalidClient(customPasswordAuthenticationToken);
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = clientPrincipal.getRegisteredClient();
        username = customPasswordAuthenticationToken.getUsername();
        password = customPasswordAuthenticationToken.getPassword();

        UserDetails user = null;
        try {
            user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException e) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException("Invalid credentials");
        }
                
        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword()) || !user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
            throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException("Invalid credentials");
        }

        authorizedScopes = user.getAuthorities().stream()
                .map(scope -> scope.getAuthority())
                .filter(scope -> registeredClient.getScopes().contains(scope))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
        //-----------Create a new Security Context Holder Context----------
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken oAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken = (OAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        CustomUserAuthorities customPasswordUser = new CustomUserAuthorities(firstName, username, user.getAuthorities());
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken.setDetails(customPasswordUser);

        var newcontext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        newcontext.setAuthentication(oAuth2ClientAuthenticationToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(newcontext);
```

I expected firstName: first name of the authenticated user to be returned. But it returned "". (empty).

```
{
  "sub": "myclientid",
  "aud": "myclientid",
  "firstName": "",
  "nbf": 1691786519,
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080",
  "exp": 1692650519,
  "iat": 1691786519,
  "authorities": [
    "ROLE_CLIENT"
  ],
  "username": "alex@gmail.com"
}
```